# Dynamic html form elements as array

Tags: html, forms

I have a dynamic section in my html form. When clicking on a button, user can add a tag name and tag type. At a point, imagine that there are 3 set of tag names and tag types, the data should be submitted in the following format.

```
Array[0][name] = tag1 name, Array[0][type] = tag1 type
Array[1][name] = tag2 name, Array[1][type] = tag2 type 
Array[2][name] = tag3 name, Array[2][type] = tag3 type
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to have a multidimensional array that can store an array within each position of the array. Assuming you have already a form, html should look something like this:

```
 <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
     <div class="inputs">
         <input type="text" name="tagName" value="">
         <input type="text" name="tagType" value="">
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="addRow">Add new tag name and type</a>
     <button type="submit" name="button">Submit form data</button>
 </form>
```

For the functionality, you could have something like this to store the information and then submit the form:

```
    //Initialization of array
    var javascriptArray = [];

    //Function to replicate fields in the form
    function replicateFields(){
        var elementToReplicate = $('.inputs').first(), //Only clone first group of inputs
            clonedElement = elementToReplicate.clone();//Cloned the element
        clonedElement.find('input').val(''); //Clear cloned elements value on each new addition
        clonedElement.insertBefore($('form a'));
    }

    //Calling function on click
    $('.addRow').click(function(){
        replicateFields();
    });

    //Go through inputs filling up the array of arrays.
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('.inputs').each(function(){
            javascriptArray.push([$(this).find('input[name="tagName"]').val(), $(this).find('input[name="tagType"]').val()]);
        });
        console.log(javascriptArray);
        return false; // remove this to submit the form.
    });
```

You can check in the console in the developer tools for the information you are about to submit.

Let me know if this helps,
Leo.

```js
//Initialization of array
        var javascriptArray = [];
        
        //Function to replicate fields in the form
        function replicateFields(){
            var elementToReplicate = $('.inputs').first(), //Only clone first group of inputs
                clonedElement = elementToReplicate.clone();//Cloned the element
            clonedElement.find('input').val(''); //Clear cloned elements value on each new addition
            clonedElement.insertBefore($('form a'));
        }

        //Calling function on click
        $('.addRow').click(function(){
            replicateFields();
        });

        //Go through inputs filling up the array of arrays.
        $('form').submit(function(){
            $('.inputs').each(function(){
                javascriptArray.push([$(this).find('input[name="tagName"]').val(), $(this).find('input[name="tagType"]').val()]);
            });
            console.log(javascriptArray);
            return false; // remove this to submit the form.
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
         <div class="inputs">
             <input type="text" name="tagName" value="">
             <input type="text" name="tagType" value="">
         </div>
         <a href="#" class="addRow">Add new tag name and type</a>
         <button type="submit" name="button">Submit form data</button>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another possibility for how to make this work. a simple form with a div to contain the tags and a small input field to add a new tag.

```js
var tagid = 1;

function addTag() {
  var div = document.getElementById("tags");
  var name = document.getElementById("tname").value;
  var type = document.getElementById("ttype").value;
  div.innerHTML += "tag" + tagid + "<br><input type='text' name='tag[" + tagid + "][name]' value='" + name + "'><br><input type='text' name='tag[" + tagid + "][type]' value='" + type + "'><hr>";
  tagid++;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form id="form">
    tags:<br>
    <div id="tags">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <hr> tag name: <input id="tname" type="text" name="tname"><br> tag type: <input id="ttype" type="text" name="ttype"><br>
  <button onclick="addTag()">add tag</button>
</body>

</html>
```